# Execute JavaScript on web browser by Java

Tags: java, javascript, browser

Is there any way to click on particular links on web browser or run some javaScripts after opening a browser using Java?

I have used this code to launch the browser. But how can I run some JS on this web browser or click any links on it by using JAVA ?

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
    if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
        try {
            URI uri = new URI("http://stackoverflow.com/");
            desktop.browse(uri);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Rather than asking about a shady technical solution (especially when you have to use something platform independent such as Java), what is your -goal-? What functional requirement do you want to achieve here? There may be far more manageable ways to achieve the same goal.

Comment: do you have to do this with java? how about .net?

Comment: I have to run few JS on another site (like clicking few links or buttons) for many times. But after each click the page will refresh and so I have to run the JS again manually(on Console panel). But I am trying to create a JAVA application which will open link in browser, click the link by JS(Which will be run by JAVA App), then the page will refresh automatically, then again clicking the link by JS and continue for an hour. How can I do that?  @Gimby

Comment: Is it easy on .net? I don't know. Please Guide me . @MihaiC

Comment: it's not that easy, but not hard either. In .net you can use the WebBrowser compoment and it's DocumentCompleted event

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jxbrowser`.

http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser

This example clicks a button with the id `button` once the page is loaded.

There are a plethora of other examples here:

https://sites.google.com/a/teamdev.com/jxbrowser-support/samples

```
public class DOMSimulateClickSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser browser = BrowserFactory.create();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(browser.getView().getComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //this will create infinite loop if your page refreshes automatically after the button press
        browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent event) {
                if (event.isMainFrame()) {
                    Browser browser = event.getBrowser();
                    DOMDocument document = browser.getDocument();
                    DOMElement link = document.getElementById("button");
                    if (link != null) {
                        link.click();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        browser.loadHTML("<html><body><button id='button' " +
            "onclick=\"alert('Button has been clicked!');\">Click Me!</button>" +
            "</body></html>");
    }
}
```

It also support running javascript (taken from their examples):

```
public class JavaScriptSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser browser = BrowserFactory.create();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(browser.getView().getComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Executes the passed JavaScript code asynchronously.
        browser.executeJavaScript("document.write('<html><title>" +
                "My Title</title><body>Hello from JxBrowser!</body></html>');");

        // Executes the passed JavaScript code and returns the result value.
        JSValue documentTitle = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("document.title");
        // Make sure that result value is a string and read its value
        if (documentTitle.isString()) {
            System.out.println("Document Title = " + documentTitle.getString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is JxBrowser an open source or should i pay for it?? @MihaiC

Comment: @Sujit as far as i know it's not open source, so you have to pay for it after a trial period.

Comment: Is there any way other than that?? I heard it can be done by using JavaFx? It it true? If it is, can you send me some guidelines @MihaiC?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use selenium !! I used chromedriver + selenium for web automation testing.

you need :

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

this is a simple example to open a site and scroll, and remove some dom :

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches",
                Arrays.asList("--disable-extensions"));

        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



        try {
            driver.get("http://sharephim.vn/");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".adv_items")));


        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
        driver.executeScript("scroll(0, 12250);");
        driver.executeScript("jQuery(\"object\").remove()");
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing and was hoping it was going to be as simple as this, but the requirement here is not automation testing.